# cv::Mat from external raw pointer data, releasing itself

Tags: c++, opencv

is there a way of creating a `cv::Mat` from external data pointer, but making that object responsible for deleting the data?

i.e., I have a function creating a `cv::Mat` from a `void *` pointer,

```
cv::Mat createMat() {

  void *data = (...);

  cv::Mat data_m(rows, cols, CV_8UC1, data);
  return data_m;
}
```

and I want that my returned `cv::Mat` to be responsible for releasing the data. How can I do this?

Comment: Why you would do that? Is not better for who create the data to relase it ?

Comment: I think no. the `Mat` releases only the data it owns. Why do you want this behavior in the first place? Isn't it better _copy_ the data into the mat, and release the `data` afterwards?

Comment: @HumamHelfawi I do this because my data comes from an external smart pointer, and I want to own that data but do not want the user to be responsible to free it in the cv::Mat

Comment: @Miki I want to avoid copying data uneccessarily

Answer (score 5):

All OpenCV functions expect `cv::Mat::data` to be a void*, so you cannot change that. If you inherit from `cv::Mat` and write your own destructor, you become incompatible from OpenCV because they do not return your derived type.
I would suggest to contain your `cv::Mat` as an attribute of a class, and keep a `std::shared_ptr` or other smart pointer to manage the lifetime of the underlying `void*`.
Just initialize the OpenCV matrix with the raw pointer from the shared pointer with `std::shared_ptr::get()`
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/shared_ptr/get/ and make sure they have the same lifetime, i.e. in the same class.

Comment: That's an interesting solution

Answer (score 1):

I come up with a solution similar to [@SpamBot](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35626686/5008845)'s one. However, you can't use `std::shared_ptr::get()` to initialize a `Mat`, since it expects a `void*`, and not a `const void*`.

In practice, you inherit from a `cv::Mat`, and keep a `shared_ptr<void>` of the data. This will free the memory once it goes out of scope.

```
#include <opencv2\opencv.hpp>
#include <memory>
using namespace cv;
using namespace std;


struct SelfDeallocMat : cv::Mat
{
    shared_ptr<void> pdata;
    SelfDeallocMat(int rows, int cols, int type, void* data, size_t step = 0U) 
        : Mat(rows, cols, type, data, step), pdata(data) {};
};

int main()
{
    uchar* pdata = new uchar[3];

    pdata[0] = 1;
    pdata[1] = 2;
    pdata[2] = 3;

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {cout << int(pdata[i]) << " "; }
    cout << endl;

    {
        SelfDeallocMat m(1, 3, CV_8UC1, (void*)pdata);
        cout << m << endl;

    }

    // Some garbage values
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) { cout << int(pdata[i]) << " "; }
    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

---

Note that if you copy the `SelfDeallocMat` to another `Mat`, but the `SelfDeallocMat` goes out of scope, the `Mat` will contain garbage values:

```
Mat n;
{
    SelfDeallocMat m(1, 3, CV_8UC1, (void*)pdata);
    n = m;
    cout << m << endl;
}
// Garbage!
cout << n << endl;
```

Comment: That's what I ended up doing. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I see two solutions for doing what you want without having to derivate to cv::Mat.

The easiest one is call `std::vector`.

```
std::vector<what_type_you_want> data = {a,b,c,d,thank_you_cpp_eleven_for_the_initializer_list};

// If you are a memory size maniac.
data.shrink_to_fit();

    cv::Mat data_m(rows,cols,type_with_or_without_channels,data.data()/*you don't need to do a reinterpret_cast<void*> it work as is*/,data.size()/*not needed*/);
```

Like this you can do what ever you want with the `cv::Mat` object while the `std::vector` destructor is not called your memory is availlable.
Then it's destroy by the std::vector destructor.

Second solution more technical but more closer about what you want to do.

If you check every Mat object have a member `allocator` this member is a pointer of type `cv::MatAllocator` what is an abstract class.

If you read the implementation of both creator you'll see it use an allocator for manage the memory allocation.
So doing what you waht you need to :
1) create your own allocator.
2) create an the object like the method create use to do it.

So more or less it look like this :

```
    #include <opencv2/core.hpp>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <cstdlib>

namespace
{    

        class MyMatAllocator : public cv::MatAllocator


   {
    public:

    cv::UMatData* allocate(int dims, const int* sizes, int type,
                       void* data0, size_t* step, int /*flags*/, cv::UMatUsageFlags /*usageFlags*/) const
    {
        std::cout<<"I am call"<<std::endl;

        size_t total = CV_ELEM_SIZE(type);
        for( int i = dims-1; i >= 0; i-- )
        {
            if( step )
            {
                if( data0 && step[i] != CV_AUTOSTEP )
                {
                    CV_Assert(total <= step[i]);
                    total = step[i];
                }
                else
                    step[i] = total;
            }
            total *= sizes[i];
        }
        uchar* data = data0 ? (uchar*)data0 : (uchar*)cv::fastMalloc(total);
        cv::UMatData* u = new cv::UMatData(this);
        u->data = u->origdata = data;
        u->size = total;
//        if(data0)
//            u->flags |= cv::UMatData::USER_ALLOCATED;


        return u;
    }

    bool allocate(cv::UMatData* u, int /*accessFlags*/, cv::UMatUsageFlags /*usageFlags*/) const
    {
        if(!u) return false;
        return true;
    }

    void deallocate(cv::UMatData* u) const
    {

        if(!u)
            return;

        CV_Assert(u->urefcount == 0);
        CV_Assert(u->refcount == 0);
//        if( !(u->flags & cv::UMatData::USER_ALLOCATED) )
//        {
            std::cout<<"deallocation"<<std::endl;
            cv::fastFree(u->origdata);
            u->origdata = 0;
//        }
        delete u;
    }
};

void create(cv::Mat& obj,int d, const int* _sizes, int _type,void* p)
{
    int i;
    CV_Assert(0 <= d && d <= CV_MAX_DIM && _sizes);
    _type = CV_MAT_TYPE(_type);

    if( obj.data && (d == obj.dims || (d == 1 && obj.dims <= 2)) && _type == obj.type() )
    {
        if( d == 2 && obj.rows == _sizes[0] && obj.cols == _sizes[1] )
            return;
        for( i = 0; i < d; i++ )
            if( obj.size[i] != _sizes[i] )
                break;
        if( i == d && (d > 1 || obj.size[1] == 1))
            return;
    }

    obj.release();
    if( d == 0 )
        return;
    obj.flags = (_type & CV_MAT_TYPE_MASK) | cv::Mat::MAGIC_VAL;
//    setSize(*this, d, _sizes, 0, true);

    CV_Assert( 0 <= d && d <= CV_MAX_DIM );
     if( obj.dims != d )
     {
         if( obj.step.p != obj.step.buf )
         {
             cv::fastFree(obj.step.p);
             obj.step.p = obj.step.buf;
             obj.size.p = &obj.rows;
         }
         if( d > 2 )
         {
             obj.step.p = (size_t*)cv::fastMalloc(d*sizeof(obj.step.p[0]) + (d+1)*sizeof(obj.size.p[0]));
             obj.size.p = (int*)(obj.step.p + d) + 1;
             obj.size.p[-1] = d;
             obj.rows = obj.cols = -1;
         }
     }

     obj.dims = d;
     if( !_sizes )
         return;

     size_t esz = CV_ELEM_SIZE(obj.flags), esz1 = CV_ELEM_SIZE1(obj.flags), total = esz;

     for( i = d-1; i >= 0; i-- )
     {
         int s = _sizes[i];
         CV_Assert( s >= 0 );
         obj.size.p[i] = s;

         obj.step.p[i] = total;
         int64 total1 = (int64)total*s;
         if( (uint64)total1 != (size_t)total1 )
             CV_Error( CV_StsOutOfRange, "The total matrix size does not fit to \"size_t\" type" );
         total = (size_t)total1;
     }

     if( d == 1 )
     {
         obj.dims = 2;
         obj.cols = 1;
         obj.step[1] = esz;
     }

    if( obj.total() > 0 )
    {
        cv::MatAllocator *a = new MyMatAllocator();

            obj.u = a->allocate(obj.dims, obj.size.p, _type, p, obj.step.p, 0, cv::USAGE_DEFAULT);
            CV_Assert(obj.u != 0);

        CV_Assert( obj.step[obj.dims-1] == (size_t)CV_ELEM_SIZE(obj.flags) );
    }

    obj.addref();


    int j;
    for( i = 0; i < obj.dims; i++ )
    {
        if( obj.size[i] > 1 )
            break;
    }

    for( j = obj.dims-1; j > i; j-- )
    {
        if( obj.step[j]*obj.size[j] < obj.step[j-1] )
            break;
    }

    uint64 t = (uint64)obj.step[0]*obj.size[0];
    if( j <= i && t == (size_t)t )
        obj.flags |= cv::Mat::CONTINUOUS_FLAG;
    else
        obj.flags &= ~cv::Mat::CONTINUOUS_FLAG;

    d = obj.dims;
    if( d > 2 )
        obj.rows = obj.cols = -1;
    if(obj.u)
        obj.datastart = obj.data = obj.u->data;
    if( obj.data )
    {
        obj.datalimit = obj.datastart + obj.size[0]*obj.step[0];
        if( obj.size[0] > 0 )
        {
            obj.dataend = obj.ptr() + obj.size[d-1]*obj.step[d-1];
            for( int i = 0; i < d-1; i++ )
                obj.dataend += (obj.size[i] - 1)*obj.step[i];
        }
        else
            obj.dataend = obj.datalimit;
    }
    else
        obj.dataend = obj.datalimit = 0;
}

void create(cv::Mat& obj, const int& rows,const int& cols, int _type,void* p)
{
    const int sizes[2] = {rows,cols};

        create(obj,2,sizes,_type,p);
    }

}

    int main(int argc,char* argv[])
    {
        uchar* toto = new uchar[10];

    std::iota(toto,toto+10,1);

    cv::Mat a;

    create(a,1,10,CV_8UC1,toto);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The smart pointer you are using actually owns the data. You want to transfer this ownership to another smart pointer which is `cv::Mat` (`cv::Mat` is a kind of smart pointer). That is not possible since there is no relation between C++ smart pointers and `cv::Mat`