# Is auto memory free possible for cv::Mat constructor with pointer to data?

Tags: c++, opencv

There is a very handy `cv::Mat` constructor in OpenCV:

```
cv::Mat::Mat(int rows,
             int cols,
             int type,
             void * data,
             size_t step = AUTO_STEP)
```

Doc says:

> The external data is not automatically deallocated, so you should take
>   care of it.

Is it possible to ask OpenCV to automatically free this memory, when Mat ends its live? (without making a Mat copy of course)

Comment: See my previous answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35626686/2079934

Comment: Possible duplicate of [cv::Mat from external raw pointer data, releasing itself](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35625698/cvmat-from-external-raw-pointer-data-releasing-itself)